# Problem with Ordered Triples

Tags: functions, logic, set-theory

I have been doing set theory for a while, and for a long time I have understood Kuratowski's inductive definition for ordered $n$-tuples:

- $(x_1,x_2) := \{\{x_1\},\{x_1,x_2\}\}$
- $(x_1,x_2,...,x_{k+1}) := ((x_1,x_2,...,x_k),x_{k+1})$

Pretty quickly I understood and accepted the beautiful result that $(x_1,...,x_n) = (y_1,...,y_n)$ if and only if $x_i = y_i$ for all $i \in \{1,...,n\}$, so I moved on and accepted this definition, thinking about ordered n-tuples as abstract objects again - happy that the set theory under the hood was working as it was supposed to.

But today I noticed a problem with this definition that I didn't see, and it is to do with ordered triples (or ordered $n$-tuples for $n \geq 3$ to be honest). Given two arbitrary sets $a$ and $b$, the ordered triple $(a,a,b)$ is defined as $((a,a),b) = \{\{\color{blue}{(a,a)}\},\{\color{blue}{(a,a)},b\}\} = \{\{\color{blue}{\{\{a\}\}}\},\{\color{blue}{\{\{a\}\}},b\}\}$.

In other words $(a,a,b) = (\{\{a\}\},b)$, and this holds for all sets.

---

Now usually we don't have a domain which includes both $a$ and $\{\{a\}\}$ (or it is clear if we are talking about ordered pairs vs ordered triples), so the distinction is usually clear. But in abstract mathematics that is certainly not always the case.

For example take the set $X = \{ \{\},\{\{\}\},\{\{\{\}\}\},...\}$. Then we can imagine the set of arbitrarily long $n$-tuples of $X$, the set $Y = \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}(\prod_{i=1}^k X)$. Then because of the above situation, many very simple and intuitive functions just straight up can't be defined.

Take the function $P_3 \colon Y \to X \cup \{*\}$ given by $P_3(x_1,...,x_k) = \begin{cases} x_3 &\mbox{if } k \geq 3 \\ 
* & \mbox{if } k < 3 \end{cases}$ where the set $*$ is some set not contained in $X$.

Straight away we run into problems as $P_3(\{\},\{\},\{\}) = \{\}$ and $P_3(\{\{\{\}\}\},\{\}) = *$, which gives us $P_3(\{\},\{\},\{\}) \neq P_3(\{\{\{\}\}\},\{\})$.

This is a problem because under Kuratowski's definition of ordered $n$-tuples, we have that $(\{\},\{\},\{\}) = (\{\{\{\}\}\},\{\})$.

---

I know that there are alternative definitions for ordered $n$-tuples, for example a definition such as:

- $(\color{red}{x_1},\color{blue}{x_2},\color{green}{x_3},...,x_k) := \{\color{red}{\{x_1\}},\color{blue}{\{x_2,\{x_2\}\}},\color{green}{\{x_3,\{x_3\},\{\{x_3\}\}\}},...\}$ where the $i$th entry nests $i-1$ times

would solve this problem (at least when *the axiom of regularity* holds), but since Kuratowski's definition is so widely accepted there must be something I am overlooking. I would love to know why this is not an issue in general mathematics.

---

EDIT: As (somewhat) pointed out in the comments, an even better definition for ordered $n$-tuples would be:

- $(x_1,...,x_n) := \{\{n\}, \{n, (x_1,...,x_n)_K\}\}$, where $(x_1,...,x_n)_K$ is Kuratowski's definition of ordered $n$-tuples

as this solves the problem and holds even in the absence of *the axiom of regularity*.

And even though it has been mentioned that this definition seems to depend on a prior construction of the natural numbers (i.e. *the axiom of infinity*), I would disagree as this is an inductive definition - allowing you to define each $n$ sequentially at each inductive step, and does not require the set $\mathbb{N}$ to exist.

Comment: If $(x_1,\ldots, x_n)=(y_1,\ldots, y_m)$, Kuratowski only guarantees $x_i=y_i$ for all $i$ if $n=m$. If $n\ne m$, it doesn't guarantee anything. To "encode" the length of a tuple with the tuple you could define $\color{blue}(x_1,\ldots, x_n\color{blue}):=(n,(x_1,\ldots, x_n))$. Then you have $\color{blue}(x_1,\ldots, x_n\color{blue})=\color{blue}(y_1,\ldots, y_m\color{blue})\iff n=m\land x_1=y_1\land\ldots\land x_n=y_n$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen While I agree with you that this would solve the issue, this is again an alternative definition for ordered $n$-tuples and not the standard one that is usually given. In other words ordered $n$-tuples need to have their length encoded into their definition for arbitrary tuples to work, even though there length is never encoded in the standard definition?

Comment: An alternative is identifying tuple $(x_1,\dots,x_{n})\in X^n$ with the function $f:n=\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}\to X$ that sends $k$ to $x_{k+1}$. Then automatically the sets $X^0,X^1,X^2,\dots$ are disjoint and the length of the tuple is its domain.

Answer (score 0):

Any set-theoretic definition of tuples has its weaknesses because we use sets to "simulate" tuples. Here for example, the length of a tuple is not uniquely determined. As soon as you know the (intended) length, it has unique element.

If this is a problem for your application, then use another definition of tuple. This is the good thing with this approach. We do not *have to* use it, it just is there to show that a sufficiently well-behaved definition is possible. It is like in algebra: it is not important what a number/vector/etc. *really* is, we only need that it satisfies specific axioms. In this case we want to have

$$(a_1,...,a_n)=(b_1,...,b_n)\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad a_i=b_i,i=1,...,n.$$

So this can be more seen as an axiom than a result (anything which does not satisfy this result is not considered a valid definition of tuple). Including the uniqueness of the length as another axiom would be a good idea though.

Comment: This is what I thought, but it just seems strange to me why Kuratowski's definition is used at all when there are better definitions that define $n$-tuples that have none of these problems (for example, where the first entry encodes the length). Are there advantages to Kuratowski's definition that I am not seeing?

Comment: @Sam Maybe it is used because it is easy to construct and deal with with only using a few axioms or complex ideas, e.g. for encoding the length you already need natural numbers. Maybe it is very uncommon that the length of a tuple is not known. Actually never thought about this weakness. But you are right. This was also the first definition of tuples that I came across in set-theory. Strange.

Comment: As I mentioned in the edit to my question, I would argue that the definition that encodes length does not depend on the construction of the natural numbers (i.e. *the axiom of infinity*) - or any additional axioms - compared to the regular definition. Maybe it really is just that it is easier to write, but it seems really strange to me why such a rigorous foundation for mathematics would not address this.

Comment: @Sam I never said you need the full set $\Bbb N$. It was more of a didactic argument. When teaching someone set theory, you have to introduce the encoding of natural numbers first befor you can use it to define tuples. I consider tuples more fundamental, so I would go the other way. By the way, I prefer your second definition as the $i$-th element can be read from the set with $i$ elements. And the (finite) number of elements of a set is unambiguous.

Comment: I misread your comment, as I thought that is what you meant by "only using a few axioms" - considering both definitions only depend on *the axiom of extensionality* and *the axiom of pairs*. I do agree that it uses more complex ideas than Kuratowski's definition (though barely), but strangely enough that also seems to be the only advantage it has.

Comment: @SamForster Take it this way: when you are going to teach someone, choose the other definition. ;)